# ASP.NET MVC validation : string starts with 000 and is followed by another 6 numbers

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am validating a string that should be 9 chars long, numbers only and must start with `000`.

I created the following validation:

```
[RegularExpression("^[0]{3}*", ErrorMessage="{0} must start with 000 and be numeric")]
[StringLength(9, MinimumLength=9, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be 9 numb long")]
public string Test{get;set;}
```

Is there better way to do it?

Comment: With a single pattern? `^000[0-9]{6}$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine.
`^000[0-9]{6}$`

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
000 matches the characters 000 literally (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]
    {6} matches the previous token exactly 6 times
    0-9 matches a single character in the range between 0 and 9 (case sensitive)
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/82I8Wm/1)